# How to upload a file in html page, using http trigger in azure functions using python?

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-functions

I would like to have a some way, how to upload a file (could be html without php, or some interactive azure upload page, whatever), and through my URL params I would like to send parameters, which will run the rest of code using this uploaded file (ofc I need to save it to blob at least).

I need a rest api, so i chose azure functions.

Is there any way how to do it in python? I saw lots of examples in C#, but docs for python are limited.

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the issue, you can use `Html Form` to implement it.

For example

1. Html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js">
</script>
<body>

 <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
</form>
<progress></progress>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(':file').on('change', function () {
  var file = this.files[0];
  console.log(file)


$(':button').on('click', function () {
  var form = new FormData()
  form.append('file',file)


    $.ajax({
    // Your server script to process the upload
    url: '<your azure function app url>',
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    // Form data
    data:form,

    // Tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
    // You *must* include these options!
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    success :  function(data){console.log(data);},

    // Custom XMLHttpRequest
    xhr: function () {
      var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      if (myXhr.upload) {
        // For handling the progress of the upload

        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
          if (e.lengthComputable) {
            $('progress').attr({
              value: e.loaded,
              max: e.total,
            });
          }
        }, false);
      }
      return myXhr;
    }
  });

});





});



});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2. Function code (upload file to Azure blob )

```
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
        file=  req.files.get('file')
        logging.info(file.filename)

        connect_str="your storage account connection string"
        container="your container name"

        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
        blob_client =blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container,blob=file.filename)
        blob_client.upload_blob(file)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.info(ex.args)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"the file {file.filename} upload successfully")
```

3. Configure CORS for you function
   [image]
4. Test
   [image]

Comment: Thx a lot, so I should create a web page hosted on azure and call an Azure function? T tried something similar, but without a separate webpage, I just put the form inside the Action, but I have read I should not use azure functions this way :)))) I was thinking to use Blob as an output of Function. Maybe its wrong idea? But I will try your idea and let you know and check your anwer ;)

Comment: @la_femme_it regarding the solution, you need to create a static web app and Azure function. You can host the static web app on Azure storage(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website).

Comment: I was not able to make it running, maybe the wrong function url...  I need to post parameters in url, which set build and some other parameters for the ml model and in the same time upload the file... Also on official docs is stated> CORS is not supported with static website.

Comment: @la_femme_it Firstly, we just need to configure CORS rule in Azure function. Secondly, if you want to send other parameters with the file, you also can use `form-data`. It likes `form.append('param1','value1')`. Then in Azure function, we can use the code `form.get('param1')` to get value

Comment: yes, that is true, but I guess, they wanted to use rest url method to trigger it... Also I allowed a CORS, but as I said, their official documentation states, CORS is not allowed in static web. I think I will deploy flask python app directly... seems much more better approach and much more managable...

Comment: @la_femme_it As far as I knew, the official document says that we can not call the static web in client side because we will face the cors error. But we can call the rest api in the static web. Besides, if you have some other needs, I think the web app is a better way.

Comment: I will try to serialize form as a json, that might work, what do you think?

Comment: @la_femme_it Sorry I cannot understand. Could you please describe it in detail? Is that you create httptrigger function and use json (it contains file content and other things ) as body when you call Azure function?