# Python Azure Function http triger from HTML file

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions

I followed the description presented on this link [How to upload a file in html page, using http trigger in azure functions using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60889319/how-to-upload-a-file-in-html-page-using-http-trigger-in-azure-functions-using-p/64330652#64330652) to build some html file that is able to send a request to a python based azure function. However, this solution makes use of the static web app.

I'd prefer to trigger the function from the local html file directly without hosting a web page. When doing so I get the following error in Chrome:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://FunctionName.azurewebsites.net/api/function' from origin 'null'
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Is there a way to achieve this? The code I'm using is the same from the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try disable CORS check about Chrome with specific args as follows:

```
chrome.exe --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir --disable-site-isolation-trials
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Is this the only possible solution?

Comment: I guess other solutions require web server (local web server, Azure Blob storage, Functions and others..).

Comment: Is there a way to call the html file directly from a container on the blob storage? This example didn't work: https://build5nines.com/static-website-hosting-in-azure-storage/

Comment: Edit: actually it works as soon as I make the container public...Why doesn't it work when it's private...

Comment: Private container require SAS token. If you'll try page host on Azure Storage,  you can choose static website hosting in $web container as follows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

Comment: Ok to access the html on a private Blob Storage Container I have to do it via SAS. This actually helped. Thanks!